# Getting / displaying all data bands in ArcMap using *.hdf data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modis, hdf

I was using modis snow cover product with ArcMap 10.1 which had 2 data bands (0,1) and suddenly it stopped showing one of the bands which i needed (1, the snow cover).

How to get that data band back ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the file to GeoTIFF:

http://newsroom.gsfc.nasa.gov/sdptoolkit/HEG/HEGHome.html